# how to convert an "empty mesh" to low poly with high detail

Tags: modeling, baking

my object is a 3d scan and is basically a shell with a mesh and image textures. i've heard about retopo but the problem is i don't have a model to retopo on. just a shell. is there another way to convert this to low poly but keep the detail?[image]

Comment: what do you meane by "empty" mesh or shell?

Comment: as in the mesh is hollow as you can see from the underside of the photo. if i was to delete all vertices my entire model would disappear